# Swift array: How to add multiple values in an index

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm trying to create a simple data model in Swift. The model is a list, in which it will have items such as name, size, colour and store.

```
struct List{

var list: [String]
var name: String
var size: String
var colour: String
var store: String

init(var list:[String], name: String, size: String, colour: String, store: String){

    self.list = list
    self.name = name
    self.size = size
    self.colour = colour
    self.store = store

    list = [name, size, colour, store]
}
```

If I were to put `list = [name, size, colour, store]` at index 0, only name is there. How do I store multiple values for one index such that

Index 0: name1, size1, colour1, store1

Index 1: name2, size2, colour2, store2

Comment: Sounds like you want an array of arrays.  or An array of objects

Comment: You're probably mixing up instance vs. type variables. `list` belongs always to the instance which is created in the `init` function and contains one item as long as the variable is not accessed from outside the `List` structure.

Answer (score 6):

You need to define a model to represent the elements of your list

```
struct Element {
    let name: String
    let size: String
    let colour: String
    let store: String
}
```

### Creating the list

```
var list = [Element]()
```

### Adding elements

```
let elm = Element(name: "name0", size: "size0", colour: "colour0", store: "store0")
list.append(elm)

let anotherElm = Element(name: "name1", size: "size1", colour: "colour1", store: "store1")
list.append(anotherElm)
```

### Extracting an element

```
let firstElm = list[0] // "name0", "size0", "colour0", "store0"
```

Answer (score 1):

swift `Tuples`, every single Element

```
struct List{
var list:  [(String, String, String, String)] = []
//    var name: String
//    var size: String
//    var colour: String
//    var store: String

init(name: String, size: String, colour: String, store: String){
    let t = (name, size, colour, store)
    self.list.append(t)
    }
}
```

or using two `struct`

```
    struct Element {
        var name: String
        var size: String
        var colour: String
        var store: String
    }


    struct List2 {
        var list:  [Element] = []

        init(name: String, size: String, colour: String, store: String){
            let t = Element(name: name, size: size, colour: colour, store: store)
            self.list.append(t)
        }
    }
```